# What considerations besides development time must I make in choosing server languages?

Tags: performance, service, microservices

I'm trying to get a better understanding of server languages / frameworks and their potential advantages and disadvantages as used in a microservice environment. Development time is not important to me since this is for my own personal project and learning to use the right tool for the problem is more important to me than the development time required to build the service.

The more I think about it, the more I think that Elixir should be used 90% of the time. The reason is twofold:

1) concurrency implies many users can hit the service without fail

2) most microservices have 0 processing overhead, they hit a database and return a json. I.e. the gains from hitting a database with a faster language are not differentiable from using a slower language. The database in question will determine the speed at which data is returned, not the server language since the database implementation will itself be written in lower language like C++. (Is this true? Will Elixir + Postgresql be noticably slower than Go + Postgresql? Or even Ruby + Postgresql? Is the bottleneck Postgresql or the language making the request?)

Assuming the above 2 are true, then it stands to reason to me that I would use Elixir 90% of the time because I would get a service that is future-proofed to traffic spikes and since it will generally have the same speed of execution as any other database retrieval Rest APIs.

The other 10% of the time where a service requires processor speed like  an Image Recognition service I would then implement in C++ or in Python because it has libraries already implemented in C++ for Image Recognition (ie Tensor Flow).

Is this a correct way of thinking about when to use specific languages for a microservice? If not, besides Development Time what else should I consider?

Comment: @enzian this question is a poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming the above 2 are true, then it stands to reason to me that I would use Elixir 90% of the time [...]

Be careful when making these kinds of statements! They tempt you into choosing the thing you always choose when setting up a new service, when actually you should be thinking about what that service is supposed to do and what languages and frameworks help you get there best! That said: your two premises are true! A DB hit is the most expensive operation and concurrency is a vital tool when handling larger loads. They are true but not complete: There are other conditions you might need to think about like resource consumption, scheduling behavior of your platform etc.

On the count of languages: Managed languages (like for example everything based on the JVM or .NET runtime) always imply a certain static overhead because their need to do garbage collection, or their need to compile code on the go, dynamic type deduction at runtime, reflection etc. This means, that they will need more memory and CPU cycles from your machines than other languages like C++, GO, Rust and the likes.

While you have to do memory management yourself in languages like C++, languages like GO, D and Rust attempt to provide a middle ground  towards fully managed languages/runtimes like JVM or .NET.

What matters at least as much as your choice in languages/runtimes is your architecture. Everything involving classic databases will probably give you troubles on the scaling side of things, Everything hitting a disk is going to kill you under load!

So what's the my suggestion? Keep all the variables in mind (Request latency is not the only metric! Resource consumption can be a killer too!), choose the best language and toolchains for whatever purpose your service has to fullfill and validate different architectures!